# Order of calculation in JS

Tags: javascript, interpreter

The interpreter built by my university, codeboot.org, offers step-by-step execution for an expression. As a result, I was able to see how the program reads an arithmetic expression. And this is where I start to confus.

For example, this expression: 10-5+(7+2)/3

We always say that we should calculate the expression in the parenthesis, as a result, this is what the order that I expect

- 7+2=9, 9/3=3, 10-5=5, 5+3=8

However, what the interpreter executes is completely different.

- 10-5=5, 7+2=9, 9/3=3, 5+3=8

Even though the result is the same, but why would it calculate 10-5 first? and what happens with "we have to calculate whatever is in the parenthesis first"? This makes me really confusing

I would like to know if this is the right behavior or not that the interpreter always goes from left to right and calculate whatever it can calculate first. Instead of jumping right into the () as we would expect

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: addition is transitive too.

Comment: @DanielA.White I suspect he doesn't need that reference, it rather seems an interpreter issue instead of a javascript thing imho, the title doesn't correctly represent the question.

Comment: When I glanced at it I saw that the parens and division had no impact on the first part so I did 10-5 first...... Probably what the interpreter did too

Comment: I found that the interpreter always goes from left to right, and calculate whatever it can calculate first. Instead of what we think, jump right in to calculate the parenthesis first.

Comment: I just want to know if this is a correct behavior. because this is not what I expect at all

Comment: Did it get the correct answer?

Comment: Yes yes it is always the right answer. I mean I know it won't really affect the answer, but u know university tends to ask you very technical question on the exam (Like order of execution) rather then just let u calculate this

Comment: Do you mean "left-to-right"?

Comment: Yes yes sorry. Left to right. I mean we always say the program will calculate the expression in the parenthesis. and without doing step by step, it does seem like this. But not until I tried this yesterday, I found out it is not what I imagined

Comment: The code goes left to right and follows the order. It is still following the order of precedence as it comes to it. Since the first part has no impact, it can be done.... runs into next step.... and breaks that up into its order of precedence. and when that is done, it goes back and does it again....

Comment: That article from the first link talks some about short-circuiting operations.  So `(a && b)` does not evaluate `b` if `a` is falsey.  This means that even if it's in parentheses, that calculation is never needed and is ignored.

Comment: But the case with conditional expression would be a bit different no? Since they designed in this way to save time I guess (Since no need to know if b is false or not if a is already false)

Comment: The point was simply that `parentheses-first` cannot be a universal rule.  Read that MDN article.  It will probably clear this up a bit.

Comment: Okay thank you for your guys help :) I will read the article and try to see if I can understand better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Do the parentheses first" is not a rule in JS. And "go from left to right" isn't really a rule either. E.g. consider `1 + 4 * 6`. Strict left-to-right would result in

- 1+4 = 5, 5*6 = 30

and that's not what JS does.

Instead, JS parses your expression into an expression tree, and then evaluates it starting at the root of the tree. (Strictly speaking, a JS implementation implementation isn't required to build a tree, but it's required to give the same results as if it did.)

For instance, your example expression `10-5+(7+2)/3` would result in a tree roughly like this:

```
AdditiveExpression:
    AdditiveExpression
        AdditiveExpression
            MultiplicativeExpression
                ... NumericLiteral         10

        -                                  -
        MultiplicativeExpression
            ... NumericLiteral             5
    +                                      +
    MultiplicativeExpression
        MultiplicativeExpression
            ... ParenthesizeExpression
                (                          (
                Expression
                   ... AdditiveExpression  7+2
                       
                )                          )
        MultiplicativeOperator             /
        ExponentiationExpression
            ... NumericLiteral             3
```

where:

- I've used indentation to convey nesting;
- I've used "..." when I've left out lots of intermediate derivations; and
- I haven't bothered to give the full sub-tree for "7+2".

(I couldn't find a way to get codeboot.org to show its parse tree. If there is some way, or if you use some other tool to show an expression's parse tree, note that it may not look exactly as above, but it should be similar enough that it will give the same behavior.)

To evaluate the expression, it starts at the root, an `AdditiveExpression` whose children are:

- another `AdditiveExpression` (for `10-5`),
- the `+` token, and
- a `MultiplicativeExpression` (for `(7+2)/3`).

The rule is to

- (a) evaluate the left operand, then
- (b) evaluate the right, then
- (c) perform the addition on the results.

So that's why (a) `10-5 => 5` is the first thing your interpreter calculates.

Next is to (b) evaluate the MultiplicativeExpression for `(7+2)/3`. The rule here is similar, so we need to:

- (b1) evaluate the left operand (the MultiplicativeExpression for `(7+2)`), then
- (b2) evaluate the right operand (the ExponentiationExpression for `3`), then
- (b3) perform the operation indicated by the MultiplicativeOperator `/`.

So (b1) `7+2 => 9` is the next thing,

then (b2) `3 => 3`,

then (b3) `9/3 => 3`.

We're now finished step (b), so we proceed to (c) `5+3 => 8`.

This matches the series of calculations that your interpreter performs.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I should have asked her instead of my professor who can't even explain in details haha. This is making everything so clear!!!!

Comment: Do you know where I can find an interpreter that can show a parse tree? Because i didn't even know this is a thing before you explain it here

Comment: https://astexplorer.net/ isn't an interpreter, but it will show you, for a given chunk of JavaScript code, the AST (abstract syntax tree) generated by 15 different JavaScript parsers. (And it supports lots of other languages too.)

Comment: Thank you so much!